# How can I use this.state within this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want to assign `this.state.currentPlayer` to `this.state.whosPlaying`. It throws the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentPlayer' of undefined at new Board`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      symbols: [X, O],
      currentPlayer: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
      fields: Array(9).fill(null),
      whosPlaying: this.state.currentPlayer,
    };
  }
```

Has someone a pattern for this?

Comment: I hope you have given a thought and you really need it this way??? Why do you want to maintain same state in two variables? Just trying to understand.

Comment: @Jonas W  I didn’t mean it to be offensive, take it easy

Comment: @JonasW. Your comment is totally fine. Would you recommend to declare 'whosPlaying' outside of this.state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference an object during initialization if you are using the object literal syntax.

If you want to set a property on state based on an existing property in the object, you can do so in the `componentWillMount()` lifecycle method.

The code would look as follows:

**Inside constructor()**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      symbols: [X, O],
      currentPlayer: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
      fields: Array(9).fill(null)
    };
}
```

**Inside componentWillMount()**

```
this.setState((prevState) => { whosPlaying: prevState.currentPlayer });
```

Note:
If you are using React 16.3+, you could consider using getDerivedStateFromProps().

Comment: it works with:
this.setState({whosPlaying: prevState.currentPlayer});

Answer (score 0):

Just use an intermediate variable:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 const currentPlayer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
 this.state = {
    symbols: [X, O],
    currentPlayer,
    fields: Array(9).fill(null),
    whosPlaying: currentPlayer,
 };
}
```

Or just set it after the object literals end:

```
this.state = { currentPlayer: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) };
this.state.whosPlaying = this.state.currentPlayer;
```

Comment: Can you actually just set the state like this? `this.state.whosPlaying = this.state.currentPlayer;`? Don't you need the `setState` method?

Comment: Yes setState is better

Comment: @bob nope. `this.state =` or `this.state.whatever` don't trigger a state update, thats why everyone tells you to use `setState` when mutating the state. However inside of the constructor this is totally fine.

Comment: @noah no, they do different things, none is "better"

Comment: @JonasW. Better for me in this case. I did it like in the second example because I want to have 'whosPlaying' in this.state. Now it gives me this waring: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted

Comment: @noah liechti how is that related to my answer?!

Comment: @JonasW. I did it like you told me to do in your answer. How can it not be related?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think react's state is supposed to be used like this. If you would like to do this I would just declare the currentPlayer before you set the state. See below for an example:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const currentPlayer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
    this.state = {
      symbols: [X, O],
      currentPlayer,
      fields: Array(9).fill(null),
      whosPlaying: currentPlayer,
    };
  }
```